maximal continuation of $\Pi_2(x)$
Consider the functions for $k\in \Bbb N$
$$ \Pi_k(x) := \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} e^{\frac{\log^k n}{\log x}} $$
$\Pi_1(x)$ converges for real $1/e<x<1$.
$\Pi_1(x)$ is a Riemann zeta function i.e. $\Pi_1(x)=\zeta \big(-\frac{1}{\log x}\big)= \sum_{n \in \Bbb N} n^{\frac{1}{\log x}}$. $\Pi_1(x)$ can be analytically continued to $\Bbb C$ where we have a simple pole at $x=1/e$ and a branch cut due to the logarithm.

What is the maximal analytic continuation of $\Pi_2(x)$?

$\Pi_2(x)$ seems like a mix between a theta and zeta function.

$\Pi_1$ will have infinitely many branch cuts corresponding to the zeros of $\zeta(s)$, not just one branch cut.

The series defining $\Pi_2$ converges for all $x$ with $\Re x>0$; I suspect that the imaginary axis is a natural boundary.

My mentor asked a similar question elsewhere where we have a dirichlet series and the sequence is the binary partition function.
